# Sequelize and Postgres - foreign key constraint "..." cannot be implemented

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to add two foreign keys into my transaction table, one of then works just fine, but the second can't be implemented.
Is there a way to set an array of foreign keys? I suppose the problem is the array, since it's the only thing different.

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.createTable('transactions', { 
        id: 
        {
             type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
             primaryKey: true,
             autoIncrement: true,
             allowNull: false,
        },
        value:
        {
          type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        clientId:
        {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          allowNull: true,
          references: { model: 'client', key: 'id'},
          onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        },
        productId:
        {
          type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER),
          allowNull: false,
          references: { model: 'products', key: 'id'},
          onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        },
        createdAt:
        {
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        updatedAt: 
        {
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
          allowNull: false,
        }
      });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.dropTable('transactions');
  }
};
```

Code Fraction:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need a foreign key of type `Array`, if your tables relationship constructed properly, can you share the other models schema too? it would be helpful to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, your foreign key is probably actually a VARCHAR or a BIGINT or something along those lines... It's probably choking to death on that... your model will end up with a hasMany relationship or something that handles the fact that you may have many products associated with a transaction through a join table of some sort.... so your tables might be something like transaction, product, transaction_product with established relationships

```
transaction.hasMany(product, {as: "Products", through: "transaction_product", foreignKey: "transaction_id"}
```

and your product model might have something like

```
product.belongsToMany(transaction, {as: "Transactions", through: "transaction_product", foreignKey: "product_id"}
```

and this would take care of the many to many you are likely trying to compensate for